# Python - Manual instantiation required no matter what?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I thought I could do this:

```
from mymodule import MyClass
import asyncio

await asyncio.gather(MyClass.myfunc1(),
                         MyClass.myfunc2(),
                         MyClass.myfunc3()
                         )
```

which produces the error: `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

So I fixed it by:

```
class1 = MyClass()
class2 = MyClass()
class3 = MyClass()
await asyncio.gather(class1.myfunc1(),
                     class2.myfunc2(),
                     class3.myfunc3()
                     )
```

This seems to work fine but I have seen other modules that allow calling it by ClassName.method() without first instantiating. Or maybe it was just accessing some property. I'm not sure. Am I doing the right thing or is there a different way?

Comment: `MyClass.myfunc1()` is legal, if `myfunc1` is a *class* method.

Comment: Without further context, it *looks* like you could write `await asyncio.gather(MyClass().myfunc1(), MyClass().myfunc2(), MyClass().myfunc3())`, assuming you don't need the reference to the object after method call returns.

Comment: @chepner in python 3.8 I think you could use walrus assignment to capture the references like `await asyncio.gather((ref1::=MyClass()).myfunc1(), MyClass().myfunc2(), MyClass().myfunc3())` but TBH it would a lot clearer just to use normal assignments

Comment: You could, but I find the assignment expression very easy to overuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` means the created object or instance(Class1,Class2 and Class3) of class `MyClass`. So while calling methods of `MyClass` you need to pass the object as parameter.
Yo can do this in two ways.
1. By using object as parameter

`Myclass.myfunc(Class1)`

2. By creating instance first.

```
Class1.myfunc()
```

The second one is best way. Here you dont need to pass parameter because Class1 is automatically used as first parameter which is self.